# Erro Hibernate Persist

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho um sistema simples de abertura / consulta de chamados. Estou com erro ao tentar inserir um novo chamado.

Comecei a utilizar Hibernate e estou com problema no "persist" para adicionar um chamado a determinada fila de chamados.

Abaixo os códigos e log:

**Classe Chamado**

```
@Entity
public class Chamado {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID_CHAMADO")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="DESCRICAO")
    @Size(max=100)
    private String descricao;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="DT_ABERTURA")
    private Date dataAbertura;

    @Column(name="DT_FECHAMENTO")
    private Date dataFechamento;


    @NotNull(message="Não pode ser vazio")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_FILA")
    private Fila fila;
```

**Classe ChamadoDAO**

```
public Chamado salvarNovoChamado(Fila fila, Chamado chamado) throws IOException{
        manager.persist(chamado);
        return chamado;
    }
```

Observação: Sei que não utilizo o parametro "fila" para nada, pois é do modelo antigo, mas ainda tenho dúvida de como o Hibernate vai puxar o ID_FILA para vincular.

**Stacktracer**

```
abr 02, 2018 1:18:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path [/arqsw_sdesk_a1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.usjt.arqsw.entity.Chamado] with root cause
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: br.usjt.arqsw.entity.Chamado
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy58.persist(Unknown Source)
    at br.usjt.arqsw.dao.ChamadoDAO.salvarNovoChamado(ChamadoDAO.java:64)
    at br.usjt.arqsw.service.ChamadoService.salvarNovoChamado(ChamadoService.java:28)
    at br.usjt.arqsw.controller.ManterChamadosController.salvarNovoChamado(ManterChamadosController.java:105)
    at br.usjt.arqsw.controller.ManterChamadosController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$28d0cc1b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at br.usjt.arqsw.controller.ManterChamadosController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d45355a0.salvarNovoChamado(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Acredito que você está passando o objeto preenchendo o id dele, por isso o erro. Ele está sendo criado ou atualizado?

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra então, eu tenho o ID da FILA de quem vai pertencer o chamado, essa FILA é um outro objeto, percebi que o mesmo ID da FILA esta indo para o ID CHAMADO também.

Comment: É isso que não pode acontecer. O id do objeto chamado é gerado pelo hibernate, dependendo de como você configura a sequence da tua PK. Veja quem adiciona essa informação no objeto e limpe o valor.

Comment: Só eu mesmo que passo o valor do ID, pois o Hibernate esta pegando o valor do meu select que tenho na JSP. Que esta com o nome de "id".

Que no caso é o mesmo nome nas duas classes, Chamado e Fila.

Comment: O objeto está sendo atualizado então, e não criado?

Comment: Sim, desculpe falei errado anteriormente. Somente atribuo os valores as classes e utilizo o persist.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75413/discussion-between-kennedy-anderson-and-giuliana-bezerra).

Comment: Ai meu problema agora esta sendo passar o objeto fila junto ao objeto chamado.

List of constraint violations:[
 ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Não pode ser vazio', propertyPath=fila, rootBeanClass=class br.usjt.arqsw.entity.Chamado, messageTemplate='Não pode ser vazio'}
]] with root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido

Problema: Atributo "fila" que é um objeto, estava sendo passado como nulo.

Solução: Alterado name do select na JSP de "fila" para "fila.id"